# After update to Android 10 api version 29, SQLite database crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

After updating my project to android 10 I got crash on database open.

Logcat report:

```
2020-11-16 09:27:52.091 20196-22102/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/bezeq.gala.preprod/databases/bezeqlocator.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:300)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:737)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:284)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:251)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1386)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:994)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:940)
        at com.bezeq.locator.dao.db.DBHelper.checkDataBase(DBHelper.java:210)
        at com.bezeq.locator.dao.db.DBHelper.create(DBHelper.java:154)
        at com.bezeq.locator.service.services.OnStartService$CreateDbFromFile.doInBackground(OnStartService.java:113)
        at com.bezeq.locator.service.services.OnStartService$CreateDbFromFile.doInBackground(OnStartService.java:101)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Code:

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bezeq.gala"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 71
        versionName "15.0.71"
        multiDexEnabled true
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "bview-" + defaultConfig.versionName);
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'gala'
            storeFile file('\\\\amam\\root\\oss\\BVieW\\Keys\\gala_signature_key.jks')
            keyPassword System.getenv("BviewKeystorePassword")
            storePassword System.getenv("BviewKeystorePassword")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        def PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL = "PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL"
        def REST_API_URL = "REST_API_URL"

        localhost_emulator {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField 'String', PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL, '"GALD"';
            buildConfigField 'String', REST_API_URL, '"http://10.0.2.2:8080/gala"';
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW Dev"]
        }
        localhost_device {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField 'String', PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL, '"GALD"';
            buildConfigField 'String', REST_API_URL, '"http://localhost:5000/gala"';
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW Dev"]
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField 'String', PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL, '"GALD"';
            buildConfigField 'String', REST_API_URL, '"http://vm-tbvwwebt1.bezeq.com:8180/gala"';
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW Dev"]
        }
        tst { // Build types may not start with 'test'
            applicationIdSuffix ".tst"
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField 'String', PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL, '"GALT"';
            buildConfigField 'String', REST_API_URL, '"http://vm-tbvwwebt1.bezeq.com:8180/gala"';
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW Test"]
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
//            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', PERMISSIONS_SYSTEM_SYMBOL, '"GALA"';
            buildConfigField 'String', REST_API_URL, '"http://bview.bezeq.com/gala"';
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW"]
        }
        preprod {
            initWith release
            applicationIdSuffix ".preprod"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "BVieW PreProd"]
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        regular {
            dimension "version"
        }
        skip_login {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/release" }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //multidex suppport for android < 5.0
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    //design stuff
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'

    //google stuff
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.2.0'
    //mint (crash report & statistics)
    implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.0.9'
    //spring framework
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
    //sliding panel
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    //circle image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //usb serial connection
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:4.5'
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue.. got the answer @Anat

Comment: I have the same issue